# How to update a property with an new object from another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I have a problem setting a `Property` on the main `thread` from another `thread`.

This is what i do at the moment:

XAML:

```
<TabControl Name="tab"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();

Binding myBinding = new Binding("ReportView") { Source = ViewModel, Mode =    BindingMode.TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged };
BindingOperations.SetBinding(tabItem, TabItem.ContentProperty, myBinding);

tab.Items.Add(tabItem);

Thread t = new Thread(DoWork);
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
t.Start();
```

DoWork Method:

When i create the `ReportPreviewView` inside the body of the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, i don't get an `exception`:

```
    public void DoWork(object sender)
        {
            //I create the relavant ViewModel
            ReportViewModel reportViewModel = new ReportViewModel(SessionContext, Mediator, Parent.ReportRequest, false);

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                        {
                            //Create the relevant View
                            ReportPreviewView reportPreviewView = new ReportPreviewView(reportViewModel) { ReportName = Parent.ReportRequest.Report.ReportName };
                            ViewModel.ReportView = reportPreviewView;
                        }));
        }
```

But this is not correct. It freezes up my UI `thread`. The creation of the `ReportPreviewView` takes quit a long time.

So then i move the creation of the `ReportPreviewView` outside the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`:

```
public void DoWork(object sender)
    {
        ReportViewModel reportViewModel = new ReportViewModel(SessionContext, Mediator, Parent.ReportRequest, false);

        ReportPreviewView reportPreviewView = new ReportPreviewView(reportViewModel) { ReportName = Parent.ReportRequest.Report.ReportName };

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        reportLoaderViewModel.ReportView = reportPreviewView;
                    }));
    }
```

As soon as `PropertyChanged`  fires i get the following exception:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Any idea how i can get around this?

Comment: Well, not sure it helps, but if your `ReportPreviewView` copy constructor is lightweight, you might just want to make a copy of that object inside `beginInvoke` and use it to set `ReportView`. But I'm almost sure that won't work. Try it, hovewer, it's just one line of code :)

Comment: The prequel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553884/instantiating-an-object-in-a-background-worker-causes-the-ui-to-freeze-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **create** UI elements on UI dispatcher thread. There is no escape. So when you say

> The creation of the ReportPreviewView takes quit a long time.

Did you anaylyse why is that? Does it have drawings, animations, heavy styles, non-virtualized panels (such as canvas)? Does it have some code in its constructor that takes time to complete?

If so, please reconsider your UI design.

In WPF the UI always **freezes** for heavy views. Even if you deserialize views using XAMLReader/Writer, the creation and hosting of the view object has to take place on UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When i say the `The creation of the ReportPreviewView takes quit a long time.`, the constructor has some code that takes a long time... No if you say, `reconsider your UI design`, what should i change then? I am new to `multithreading`, so i learn on the go...

Comment: So can that code which takes time be put into `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: Yes, i can do that... Would that be a viable solution then? All the lengthy operations in my constructors must be in their own `thread/task`?

Comment: Of course. Background worker is suitable as it provides dispatcher driven **`WorkCompleted`** event. It also provides **Progress Notification** event Also being a background thread it can close when main application closes. It is also handled by thread pool internally.

Comment: I tried putting the `heavy lifting` in a background worker, but still no luck. The `ReportPreviewView` creates a another view inside the constructor and inside the new view's constructor there are more `heavy lifting`. I tried putting all of `heavy lifting` in `tasks/background workers`, but then i get `The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.`. I am stuck and don't know where to go from here... Do u maybe have any other advice i could try?