# Clipboard.getImage not working inside a thread

Tags: c#

I was trying to read images from the clipboard and save it in a specified folder using `Clipboard.getImage()`

The function works fine if it standalone. When I was using the function inside a thread its not working.

Comment: _It is not working_ is not a good explanation about problem. What is your full code? Do you get any exception or error message? Be more specific..

Comment: MSDN: "The Clipboard class can only be used in threads set to single thread apartment (STA) mode."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a STA vs MTA thread issue. You won't have access to the clipboard from a MTA thread. for reference:

This works:

```
    [STAThread()]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();
        img.Save(@"c:\temp\myimg.png",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

This doesn't - null reference:

```
    [MTAThread()]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();
        img.Save(@"c:\temp\myimg.png",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

Have a look at this thread for STA background thread related solutions:
[How can I make a background worker thread set to Single Thread Apartment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685237/how-can-i-make-a-background-worker-thread-set-to-single-thread-apartment)

Answer (score 0):

When you trying to read images from the clipboard inside a thread you must set thread ApartmentState to STA. Try this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(DoSomething());
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```